# Reversing easing function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, math, easing

I have the following function:

```
Math.easeIn = function (val, min, max) {
  strength = 4;
  val /= max;
  return (max-1)*Math.pow(val, strength) + min;
};
```

Given `Math.easeIn(5, 1, 10)`, I get `1.5625`. I would like a function that given a val of `1.5625`, it returns `5`.

I.e. `Math.easeOut(1.5625, 1, 10)` -> `5`

My math skills are letting me down here.

Comment: There are many functions that could generate that result.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
Math.easeIn = function (val, min, max) {
  strength = 4;
  val /= max;
  return (max-1)*Math.pow(val, strength) + min;
};

Math.easeOut = function (val, min, max) {
  var strength = 4, res;
  res = (val-min)/(max-1);
  res = Math.pow(res, 1/strength);
  return max*res;
};

document.body.innerHTML = '<p>easeIn : ' + Math.easeIn(5, 1, 10) + '</p>';

document.body.innerHTML += '<p>easeOut : ' + Math.easeOut(1.5625, 1, 10) + '</p>';
```

I obtained this by reversing your `easeIn` function:

```
res = (max - 1) * Math.pow(val/max, strength) + min     // Your easeIn function
res - min = (max - 1) * Math.pow(val/max, strength)
(res - min)/(max - 1) = Math.pow(val/max, strength)
Math.pow( (res - min)/(max - 1), 1/strength ) = val / max
Math.pow( (res - min)/(max - 1), 1/strength ) * max = val   // Your easeOut function
```

Comment: Thank you for this and the explanation of how you achieved it. This will certainly aid my math skill.

Comment: @Azriel You're welcome. Sorry about the formatting, it looks better on paper! [Here is a better view](http://i.imgur.com/3EsqKNq.jpg).

Comment: I actually found it very easy to follow, I just needed a nudge in the right direction :) It suddenly brought back memories of classes spent balancing equations. But thanks for putting in the extra effort and uploading an image - it's even clearer now.